# How much can you tow with a steam vehicle and still have the ability to turn?

Tags: steampunk, vehicles

**How much can you tow with a steam vehicle and still have the ability to turn?** We are working with very early steam engines, so multiple pistons are not fancied, but accepted. Size is of no mater unless you go *very* overboard, I do not want to drive the Titanic afterall (also I am pretty sure it wasn't steam powered) I am looking for something that

- can turn tightly considering size
- can be powered with primitive fuels
- Is reliable
- Does not need special driveways, has to be able to fell some trees on its way and cross ditches (this implies a tank, but I'm not going to mandate it).
- Can stay on as long as supplied fuel (closed steam cycle, other fluids can be used for cooling.)

With all above requirements how much power can such machine exert on trailer at highest possible in earth-like enviroment?

Comment: Titanic was equipped with three main engines—two reciprocating four-cylinder, triple-expansion steam engines and one centrally placed low-pressure Parsons turbine—each driving a propeller.

Comment: What you can tow depends on force/torque, which with proper gearing can be pretty much whatever you want. You're not going to be towing very fast unless you have adequate power though, which is what's going to be your limiting factor. But you don't mention a speed requirement...

Comment: How you make the power isn't really related to how you use it.

Comment: With a tracked vehicle you can turn on a dime, there is no limitation there related to engine. Maybe I should really ask how fast you want your vehicle to move?

Comment: @Alexander, a tracked vehicle can turn on a dime, a tracked vehicle towing a trailer cannot without damaging the trailer.

Comment: @JBH true, but then it's about the geometry of towing and still has nothing to do with the engine.

Comment: @Alexander, not completely.  I used to drive delivery trucks with trailers of differing weights.  A light-weight trailer could be turned more sharply than a heavy trailer because the engine couldn't drag the non-turning trailer wheels through the turn at that weight.  The OP has an interesting question  that could benefit from some clarification (tracked vehicles have fewer problems powering through turns than wheeled, for example), but it's not as simple as you've made it.

Comment: @Alexander: You don't even need tracked vehicles.  The common skid-steer loader (AKA "Bobcat") can turn in its own length.  Articulated 4WD farm tractors & construction equipment can turn on a quarter, if not exactly on a dime :-)  As others have said, your power source (as long as it fits in the machine) is irrelevant to turning radius.

Comment: @Alexander, what I am looking for is how big can be steam engine before it gets too heavy to drive and turn. Speed should be at least 2 m/s.

Comment: @KarolOfGutovo you can build a steam tank, like L.Dutch had proposed. Then you can build another tank and attach the two together. Then you can build the third and fourth tank, and... you got the idea? The entire construction, if properly synchronized, will be able to move and turn, but would become impractical well before you reach any hard limits.

Comment: I assume you are not looking for a train. Obviously it's the classical steam engine hauling trailers.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for something similar to a better developed [steam tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_tank), weighing about 50 tons.

> The Steam Tank (Tracked) was an early U.S. tank design of 1918 [...] the two main 2-cylinder steam engines with a combined power of 500 hp (370 kW) remained, each engine driving one track to give a maximum speed of 4 mph (6 km/h). The transmission allowed two speeds forward and two in reverse. The steam engines used kerosene for fuel. [...] The design combined serious cooling problems with a dangerous vulnerability due to its two steam boilers and large fuel reservoirs needed to heat the two main engines, and feed both the auxiliary engine and the flame thrower.

Since this was just an early design, it's plausible that further research and refinement could have improved the performances.

Answer (score 2):

About "how much can you tow" you can look at the last big steam tractors. [This article](https://www.farmcollector.com/steam-traction/the-legendary-150-hp-case-steam-traction-engine) say

> The Case 40 x 150 HP Traction Engine was designed for heavy hauling, such as ore from the Sater Copper Mine, carrying lumber and freight loads up to 50 tons.

One big problem at that time was

> The two-speed gear arrangement led to the end of production because there was no available metal alloy good enough in those days to hold up on such huge engines.

It certainly could move a 2 m/s or more, with the adequate gearing, and for the turn radius, it will depend on what it would be being towed.

[Here](https://youtu.be/FuJbfrcFKyU?t=620) you can see one monster of these pulling 44 bottom ploughs across a field.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlsNNfzsJDI for a tracked steam tractor